# Create VPN to lock down access to admin login page

Tags: security, vpn, wordpress

I want to limit access to my wordpress site to people who are connected to a vpn.

I dont want to setup a separate VPN server as literally the only function of this vpn is to block everyone else out of the admin page url.

Is it a bad idea to install the vpn server on the same server as the website which we are wanting to limit access to ? what are the pitfalls. as I said it is just to limit access to folks who need to update content and block all other IPs from wordpress admin